# Add wrapping to certain controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, silverlight

I need to add wrapping to my Radio Button controls all but for on one window. I am stuck trying to figure out how I can conditionally remove or change the value of my wrap panel from my control when the radio buttons are added to a different page that does not need wrapping.

This is the coding to add the wrapping.

**XAML**

```
<Style TargetType="auc:APRadioButtonListBox">
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource FontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,0,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel Background="Transparent" ItemWidth="Auto" x:Name="RadioListWrapPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
```

**C#**

```
  public virtual ItemsPanelTemplate ItemsPanel { get; set; }
```

Can anybody advice me on how to add Radio buttons to another page without the wrapping.

Comment: At what level is this style defined? The apps resource dictionary, or a specific page/container control?

Comment: Apps Resource dictionary @Fabulous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the style applied at the application level, it will be applied implicitly to all controls that match its target type. You have two options to get a page without wrapping...

- Override the style on the required pages with a style that omits the wrapping
- Give the default style you have a key and explicitly apply it where it's needed and others won't have the wrapping.

The latter makes sense if more pages have no need for the wrapping than those that do. Consider the following

```
<Style x:Key="WrappedRadioButtons" TargetType="auc:APRadioButtonListBox">
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource FontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,0,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel Background="Transparent" ItemWidth="Auto" x:Name="RadioListWrapPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
</Style>
```

Now in the pages you need to apply this style, you can do the following:

```
<uac:APRadioButtonListBox Style="{StaticResource WrappedRadioButtons}" />
```

Any other that doesn't explicitly reference this style will get the default settings. Alternatively, you can define the other style without wrapping and give it a key that you can apply to the pages that don't require the wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

create a new style derived from base and override style setter on a page where WrapPanel is not required

```
<Style TargetType="auc:APRadioButtonListBox" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type auc:APRadioButtonListBox}}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

or simply do it for auc:APRadioButtonListBox element:

```
<auc:APRadioButtonListBox>
    <auc:APRadioButtonListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </auc:APRadioButtonListBox.ItemsPanel>
</auc:APRadioButtonListBox>
```

alternatively define a named style in resource dictionary which doesn't set ItemsPanel. default style will extend it. and on one page which doesn't need wrapping use named style:

```
<Style TargetType="auc:APRadioButtonListBox" x:Key="APRadioButtonListBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource FontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,0,0,0" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="auc:APRadioButtonListBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource APRadioButtonListBoxStyle}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel Background="Transparent" ItemWidth="Auto" x:Name="RadioListWrapPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<auc:APRadioButtonListBox Style="{StaticResource APRadioButtonListBoxStyle}"/>
```